# Codeigniter Paging is Showing Empty Page after Page1

Tags: php, jquery, html, codeigniter, pagination

I am trying to create pagination in my project. I have successfully created the pagination on page 1. Its showing me 8 Records on it. But when i click on Page 2, it gives the `Page Not found` Page.

The Url on first page is

> localhost/pagination/index.php/pagination/pagination_rows

The Url on Second page shows this only,

> localhost/pagination/pagination/8

I have written the following code to accomplish this.

> **Model**

```
    public function courses_list($limit, $start)
    {
        $this->db->limit($limit, $start);
        $this->db->select('*');
        $this->db->from('courses');
        $this->db->order_by('in_semester');

        $query=     $this->db->get();

        return $query->result();
        }
```

> **Controller**

```
    public function pagination_rows() {
    $config["base_url"] = base_url() . "pagination";
   // $config["total_rows"] = $this->Countries_Model->record_count();
   $config["total_rows"] = 100;
    $config["per_page"] = 8;
    $config["uri_segment"] = 2;

    $this->pagination->initialize($config);

    $page = ($this->uri->segment(2))? $this->uri->segment(2) : 0;

    $data["courses_list"] = $this->loginmodel->courses_list($config["per_page"], $page);

    $data["links"] = $this->pagination->create_links();

    $this->load->view("courses_list", $data);
    }
```

> **View**

```
foreach ($courses_list as $courses_records)
{
    $course_id=         $courses_records->CourseId;

    $course_name=       $courses_records->CourseName;
    $credit_hours=      $courses_records->CreditHours;
    $in_semester=       $courses_records->in_semester;


....
...
..
}


<div style="text-align:center"><?php echo "Links  ".$links; ?></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

I guess there is some problem in your controller code

You can replace

```
$config["base_url"] = base_url() . "pagination";
```

With

```
$config["base_url"] = site_url('pagination');
```